# Spring 4.1.0 and aspectj: cannot catch exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, aspectj

I have a Spring MVC application using Spring 4.1.0. Part of my code is generated (by MyEclipse), and since I periodically have to regenerate it due to DB changes, I chose to use aspects to add methods and properties to the generated classes without losing my customizations with each regeneration.

Recently I decided to get rid of Eclipse building, and wanted to use Maven instead. I got myself a Bamboo server, found out all the dependencies I needed, and the build seems to complete fine. However, when I deploy to tomcat the WAR I made using maven, I have a problem: the methods I am adding with aspects are not able to catch their own raised exceptions. For example, here's an aspect I am using to add a method to a generated class:

```
public Elementvalue ElementvalueDAOOligoExtension.getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(Integer elementid, java.util.Calendar date, Double value, Integer elementvalueid, int startResult, int maxRows) throws DataAccessException {
    try {
        Query query = createNamedQuery("getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod", startResult, maxRows, elementid, date, value, elementvalueid);
        return (ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.domain.Elementvalue) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you see, the idea is that if I get no results for the query, I return null (which is then treated properly by the caller). However, when this method is called, the NoResultException actually bubbles up to the caller, and I can find it in the logs:

```
    org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:392)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod_aroundBody20(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:145)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$AjcClosure21.run(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.ajc$interMethod$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ElementvalueDAOOligoExtension$getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:141)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.dao.ElementvalueDAOImpl.getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(ElementvalueDAOImpl.java:1)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ElementvalueDAOOligoExtension$getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod_aroundBody18(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:137)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$AjcClosure19.run(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.aspects.dao.ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.ajc$interMethod$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ch_oligofunds_oligoworld_aspects_dao_ElementvalueDAOImplAspect$ElementvalueDAOOligoExtension$getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(ElementvalueDAOImplAspect.aj:136)
    at ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.dao.ElementvalueDAOImpl.getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod(ElementvalueDAOImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    ...
```

The fourth-to-last line points to the line of code above where I return the single result of the query. So, I would expect that a NoResultException at that point would be caught by the catch section, which apparently does not happen.

I should point out that everything works fine when I build in Eclipse. So I suppose there's some fundamental difference in how eclipse builds this and how standalone maven with aspectj-maven-plugin manages things (which is also hinted by the fact that standalone maven creates a bunch of $AjcClosureXXX.class files, which are not present if I build with Eclipse).

Anybody can offer a pointer in the right direction? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding about the way maven is building this code with respect to how Eclipse does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is Spring's `JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect` from `spring-aspects` in action. It wraps call sites to methods of `EntityManager`, `EntityManagerFactory`, `EntityTransaction` and `Query`, and converts exceptions raised in those method calls and wraps them with a Spring specific `DataAccessException` subtype if possible.

The difference between your Eclipse based build and your Maven build is most likely that your Eclipse build uses the Java compiler while your Maven build is using either the AspectJ compiler or the Java compiler **and** AspectJ weaver. So the Spring `JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect` does take effect in your Maven based build but not in your Eclipse based build.

Try catching the Spring specific wrapper `EmptyResultDataAccessException` instead of `NoResultException` or disable the `JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect` so your JPA exceptions don't get converted.

Also, you should install the AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) plugin into Eclipse and configure your projects to use the AspectJ compiler instead of the Java compiler so that your Eclipse and Maven build are the same.

Comment: Thanks, that both points to a solution and makes things clearer. I will try these (in the meantime I have found aworkaround by using `query.getResultList` instead of `query.getSingleResult`, and I return `null` if the returned list is empty, but that of course does not solve the general problem).

Comment: Installing the AJDT plugin would also help you a lot with these kind of issues, because it shows you nice little markers in your editor area for those lines where AspectJ affects your code in any way. With the plugin in place, you'd have a little marker in your `getDrawdownRecoveryPeriod` method on the return line, and hovering your mouse on that marker would show that indeed, the `JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect` might affect that line.